# Compare two strings in lamdba comparator function placing one in front of the other depending on if the strings contain a word

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

I'm just coming to grips with lambda functions in Java

I have an array list of class objects.

```
cars.add(new Car( "BMW",  "1 Series", 39345));
cars.add(new Car( "Nissan",  "micra", 16895 ));
cars.add(new Car( "Volkswagon",  "Golf", 23950));
cars.add(new Car( "Skoda",  "Superb", 32080));
cars.add(new Car( "Kia",  "Sportage", 36450));
```

I want to sort the cars based on model so for example I want all Skoda cars placed at the beginning of the array list.

I know for example how to sort the cars by price because it's simply comparing two prices.

```
Comparator<Car> byCost = (Car obj1, Car obj2) -> obj1.getPrice() - 
                 obj2.getPrice();
         
Collections.sort(cars, byCost);
```

I don't know how to use the Comparator function to sort the cars by name. Since I'm comparing two boolean values by using the .contains method, I cannot use the Comparator interface method like I have above. So this is what I've tried.

```
Comparator<Car> bySkoda = (Car obj1, Car obj2) -> {
    if(obj1.getModel().contains("Skoda"))
        return 1;
    else 
        return -1;
};

Collections.sort(cars, bySkoda);
```

This is of course not how to do it. I would like a pointer as to how I can achieve this using a lambda Comparator interface?

Comment: That is a lambda. What is it about your solution you want to eliminate? You say "of course" but it's not obvious so please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ternary operator may help you to get rid of `if` statement inside the lambda:

```java
final String c = "Skoda";
Comparator<Car> bySkoda = (car1, car2) -> 
    c.equals(car1.getModel()) ^ c.equals(car2.getModel()) 
        ? c.equals(car1.getModel()) ? -1 : 1 // either of c1 or c2 is "Skoda"
        : car1.getModel().compareTo(car2.getModel()); // both or none of c1, c2 is "Skoda"
```

Notes:

- the type of arguments in lambdas may be skipped if it can be inferred
- it seems to be fine to use `equals` instead of `contains`
- to place `Skoda` models first, we use XOR to check if both `car1` and `car2` are `"Skoda"`

```
|--------------------|-------------------|-----------|--------------|
|     "Skoda"        |     "Skoda"       |    XOR    |    Result    |
|.equals(car1.model) |.equals(car2.model)|           |              |
|--------------------|-------------------|-----------|--------------|
|          true      |         true      |   false   |        0     |
|          true      |         false     |   true    |       -1     |
|          false     |         true      |   true    |        1     |
|                    |                   |           | car1.model   |
|          false     |         false     |   false   | .compareTo   |
|                    |                   |           | (car2.model) |
|--------------------|-------------------|-----------|--------------|
```

- it seems reasonable to keep other models sorted in alphabet order

This may be updated to provide a sorted list with a preferable model first:

```java
public static List<Car> sortWithPreferableModelFirst(List<Car> cars, String model) {
    return cars.stream()
               .sorted((car1, car2) ->
                       model.equalsIgnoreCase(car1.getModel()) ^ model.equalsIgnoreCase(car2.getModel()) 
                       ? model.equalsIgnoreCase(car1.getModel()) ? -1 : 1 
                       : car1.getModel().compareTo(car2.getModel()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

cars = sortWithPreferableModelFirst(cars, "Skoda");
```

Comment: Would be nice if `sortWithPreferableModelFirst()` simply returned the comparator instead of actually sorting a list.

Comment: @erickson, my intention was to provide an example of sorting the list using `Stream::sorted`

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: It looks like this would violate the comparator requirement that, "The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y," in the case where both cars have the preferred model. (It should return zero in that case, rather than -1 when the objects are swapped.) Leave a comment @ me when fixed.

Comment: @erickson, updated the answer using XOR to join comparison of both models to the predefined constant